# Helm: How to overrride the values of subcharts using parent chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have an umbrella structure like that:

```
 -app1
  templates/...
  values.yaml
 -app2
  templates/...
  values.yaml
  values/dev.yaml
```

I want to be able to deploy the entire umbrella with different values file according to different environment (dev, prod), of the sub chart

1. app2 to be installed with values.yaml only
2. app2 to be installed with values.yaml and the values/dev.yaml

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope that's not possible, but there is a workaround to achieve the functionality, a change in the directory structure will be required. Before reading any further check out the similar question here
[How to set environment related values.yaml in Helm subcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590788/how-to-set-environment-related-values-yaml-in-helm-subcharts)

The above scenario can be achieved with the following directory structure:

```
test-umbrella - Chart.yaml
      - values.yaml
      - requirements.yaml
      - charts - test-dev - Chart.yaml
                           - values.yaml
               - test-prod - Chart.yaml
                           - values.yaml
      - templates - deployment.yaml
                  - _helpers.tpl
                  - secret.yaml
```

The chart dependencies should be defined like this:
**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - name: tesy-dev
    repository: "file://charts/test-dev"
    version: ">= 0.0.1"
    tags:
      - dev-values
    import-values:
      - data

  - name: test-prod
    repository: "file://charts/test-prd"
    version: ">= 0.0.1"
    tags:
      - prd-values
    import-values:
      - data
```

Parent chart's values.yaml file should contain values like this:

**values.yaml**

```
# Default values

tags:
  dev-values: false
  prd-values: false
```

And then finally you should install it with the following flag **--set tags.dev-values=true**

In umbrella chart you must be having a parent values.yaml file. If you define your keys there, then the values of subcharts will be overwritten by it.

So you can have a values-dev.yaml outside the subchart to overwrite the internal subchart values.

Moreover you should have all the values that can be changed accordingly due to environment in the parent charts values.yaml so that they can be overwritten easily.

Please check best practices and flow of execution https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/

Comment: I'm not sure how it answers my issue. I have 2 different subchart. app1 and app2. for app2 I want to have option for multiple values file according to the environment. from what you wrote I understand you want to have the environments as subcharts?

Comment: No subcharts can be anything. However there is no straightforward command to use a different values.yaml file inside subchart. That being said you can only have one **values.yaml** file with the same name inside a subchart. That file should have some maps of values as *default:* should have all the values of default values.yaml and *exception:*. Then in parent values.yaml file you should have all the enteries that can be overwritten with **global:** key. That's the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: If you have other values.yaml file inside subchart it won't be used and is good for nothing. It can be used only if you traverse to the subchart directory and use a -f to select that values.yaml but from the parent chart directory to use another values file is not possible.

Comment: The docs in helm shows only the above ways of achieving it. Any other way to do that is not itself mentioned in docs so that being said is not possible. Creating a values folder and a values.yaml there, nope that's not how helm works.

Comment: alright, thanks for the clarification and explanation. I guess I'll try your suggestion and get a feedback

Comment: I have implemented the way you suggested, once I have added the dev chart I got an error ```Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory:```